# 20.04 Setting up hibernation with full disk encryption

Tags: partitioning, encryption, swap, hibernate

I recently installed 20.04 with full disk encryption and wanted to setup my laptop to allow hibernation. I followed [this guide](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-linux) on the matter, and this didn't work. Then I found [this entry on the Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap) about setting up hibernation with an encrypted swap, and I thought that maybe that was why it didn't work. I tried following the instructions, but at the step `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXN cryptswap1` I got an error message about a header not being read properly.

At this point I am quite lost regarding the current situation with my swap. My questions are then:

1. If my entire disk is encrypted (root, swap, home, all of it), does that mean I need to follow that entry on the Ubuntu documentation?
2. What is the difference between `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1` and `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1`? Are they both partitions? Which one is my swap partition?
3. What is the difference between `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1` and `/dev/vgubuntu/swap_1`? Are they the same? If I want to reformat my swap partition, which one do I need to format?

Regarding my system, here's some possibly useful info:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=535df676-f16d-4bcd-b548-04e6152d7d07 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=A43A-6AC9  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0


$ cat /etc/crypttab 
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=fed8837c-92dc-4985-80db-38338dc84338 none luks,discard

~$ df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                      3.1G  2.3M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  915G  484G  385G  56% /
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                       16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                  98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop3                 9.2M  9.2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop2                  55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop4                 218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop0                 119M  119M     0 100% /snap/chromium/1424
/dev/loop6                  50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop5                  63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop7                 163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop8                 256M  256M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop10                 65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop11                 56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/nvme0n1p2             705M  410M  244M  63% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M  7.8M  504M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/loop12                 32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10492
/dev/loop13                 52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop14                 32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop15                 98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10583
tmpfs                      3.1G   52K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I think you will find that Ubuntu doesn’t fully support hibernation. I believe it works on some machines but not on others.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed that might be the case. At this point I have no swap defined anymore, so I was hoping some clarification regarding the `/dev/*` drives would help me sort that out.